# Batch export specified location text in file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want export specified location text in file...

e.g. 001.TXT (There may be multiple lines...)

```
1111 |END ASDQWE 22222 |END QWEASD 33333333 |END ZXCASD
44 |END ASDQWEQWE
```

Action: Find and export text position before `|END`

Result:

```
1111
22222
33333333
44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("path+001.txt") do (
  set "current_line=%%a"
  set "current_line=!current_line: |END=+END!"
  call :sub_1 !current_line!
)
exit /b    

:sub_1
set "current_value=%1"
if not defined current_value exit /b
if "%current_value:~-4,4%" EQU "+END" (
  echo %current_value:+END=%
)
shift
goto sub_1
```

Comment: Can remove the space on end of word and support different length of text? Thank you!!!

e.q: 000.txt

11111 |END ASDQWE 22222 |END QWEASD 333333333 |END ZXCASD
44 |END ASDQWEQWE

Output:

11111
22222
333333333
44

Comment: You can try it. It's also suitable for your new example.